# define target variable in glm r

Tags: r, glm

I want to be able to define my target variable 'def_target' outside the regression code below:

```
model1 <- glm(def_target~., family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train70)
```

I have tried the following but get an error pop up

```
tv1 <- 'def_target' 
model1 <- glm(tv1~., family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train70)
```

If anyone could help me that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: what kind of error message do you get? and can you post the whole code?

Comment: This is the error:
Error in model.frame.default(formula = tv1 ~ ., data = train70, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : variable lengths differ (found for 'Monthly_turn')           If I remove tv1 and subsitute it with def_target the code runs fine.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might tip up cause you tell it in your model1: `glm(tv1~., family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train70)`. train70 does not have a matching column. Try to assign your variable directly, i.e.

```
tv1 <- train70[['def_target']]
```

then

```
model1 <- glm(tv1~., family=binomial(link='logit'))
```

I must admit I am not familiar with the "." you have in there. But make sure to relate that to your original dataset like you did with tv1.

Answer (score 0):

`glm()` requires the first argument to be of class "forumla", and simply inserting a string (i.e., `'def_target'`) will not parse correctly. You need to turn the argument into a formula by using `as.formula()`, but the entire formula you want to use must be included. Here's code that works:

```
model1 <- glm(as.formula(paste(tv1," ~ .")), family=binomial(link='logit'), data=train70)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help