# specify only target variable in GLM.jl

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

In [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364122/define-target-variable-in-glm-r) there is the possibility to specify only the target variable with the formula object: `y ~ .`

This doesn't work in `GLM.jl`.

Comment: Not sure what the question is?

Comment: See answer by Dan below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R the dot notation in a formula means all fields except the dependent field (on the LHS of formula). Apparantly `GLM.jl` does not implement this notation, but this can be changed.

For example, the following functions make things a little closer to R:

```
using DataFrames    # install with Pkg.add("DataFrames")
using MacroTools    # install with Pkg.add("MacroTools")

function usedot!(f, df)
    vs = collect(filter(x->x != f.lhs,names(df)))
    ex = length(vs)>1 ? Expr(:call,:+,vs...) : vs[1]
    f.rhs = MacroTools.postwalk(x -> x == :(:.) ? ex : x , f.rhs)
    f.rhs = MacroTools.postwalk(x -> typeof(x)==Expr &&
      x.head==:quote && length(x.args)==1 &&
      x.args[1] == :. ? ex : x , f.rhs)
    return f
end

usedot(f,df) = usedot!(DataFrames.Formula(f),df)
```

These functions can be used as follows:

```
julia> using GLM, RDatasets

julia> form = dataset("datasets", "Formaldehyde");

julia> lm1 = fit(LinearModel, usedot(@formula(OptDen ~ :.),form), form)
DataFrames.DataFrameRegressionModel{GLM.LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,Base.LinAlg.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

Formula: OptDen ~ 1 + Carb

Coefficients:
               Estimate  Std.Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.00508571 0.00783368 0.649211   0.5516
Carb           0.876286  0.0135345  64.7444    <1e-6
```

But, of course, a DataFrame with more fields should be used in practice.
Changing `GLM.jl` to include dot notation should also not be this hard, but note the need to attach a Formula to a DataFrame before the dot has a concrete meaning and perhaps this is the reason it was avoided so far.

Comment: So far I'm getting the impression that `ScikitLearn.jl` is the go-to machine learning library in terms of integration with DataFrames.